# 500 Error while create template in Laravel 5 Blade

Tags: php, laravel-blade, template-engine, laravel-5

I am creating template layout for one of my website. While creating template layout i am getting 500 error on @include statement. If i remove all includes then page loaded properly, but when i include the @include statement, i am always getting 500 error on my web page.

I have listed all my effort till now. Please look into:

**Effort**

1. views

   - home

     - index.blade.php

   2.layouts

   - default.blade.php
   - layout.blade.php

   3.includes

   - defaultheader.blade.php
   - footer.blade.php
   - head.blade.php
   - header.blade.php

**Code:**

```
**index.blade.php**

@extends('layouts.default')
@section('content')
    i am the home page
@stop


**default.blade.php**

<html>
    <head>
        @include('includes.head')
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <header id=header" class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <img src= "{{ URL::asset('img/logo.png') }}" alt="Alt Text"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                        <div class="container">

                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </header>
            <section class="row">
                <div class="container">
                    <div id="content" class="col-lg-12">
                        @yield('content')
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <footer id="footer" class="row">
                <div class="container">
                   @include('includes.footer')
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

**head.blade.php**

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="Scotch">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Title | @yield('title')</title>


{{ HTML::script('js/jquery-1.12.1.min.js'); }}
{{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap.min.js'); }}

{{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.css'); }}
{{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap-theme.css'); }}
{{ HTML::style('css/style.css'); }}

**footer.blade.php**

<div id="copyright text-right">© Copyright 2016 {{ $dateY }} testing.</div>
```

**Updated**

```
'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
        Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,

    ],
'aliases' => [

        'App'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Artisan'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Cache'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'DB'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent'  => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Lang'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Password'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'Redirect'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        'Redis'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'URL'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
        'Form'      => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
        'HTML'      => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,

    ],
```

Even image also not loading.

Please suggest me the solution, I have tried everything.

Thanks,

**Updated**

```
error log on chrome browser dev tool
```

[image: browser debug tool screenshot]

**Page source view**

```
<html>
        <head>
             <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Scotch">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>TruShiled In. LMS | New Title</title>


    <script src="http://localhost/testing/js/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://localhost/testing/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/testing/css/bootstrap.css">

    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/testing/css/bootstrap-theme.css">

    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/testing/css/style.css">



        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <header id=header" class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <img src= "http://localhost/testing/img/logo.png" alt="TruShield Security Inc. LMS"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                        <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                            <div class="container">

                            </div>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </header>
                <section class="row">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div id="content" class="col-lg-12">
                                i am the home page
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <footer id="footer" class="row">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div id="copyright text-right">© Copyright 2016 - 2017 Testing Inc.</div>                </div>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: See apache error log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine. Try to temporarily delete everything from `head` and `footer` templates (keep them as empty files). If you'll still have an error, check for last error(s) in `/storage/logs/laravel.log`. Please reply me here when you'll get new info.

Comment: actually problem is with the loading the resources like css, js, img. I am using collective dependency. I am updating my code for the same please look.

Comment: What exactly related error(s) do you see in /storage/logs/laravel.log , apache log or browser debug tools?

Comment: i have look into browser debug and getting lots off error related to css, js, images. I am came to know that problem is related to resources only. If i removed these resources from template files then template engine is working fine.

Comment: Great, what are these messages? You can please update your post with these error messages, so it'll be possible to help you to fix the problem.

Comment: Updated. Kindly check, is there to define route for these resources ?

Comment: I can see that Laravel gives you html (not just 500 error), so look at source code of generated web page and please post part with generated <script...> and <link....>

Comment: Enable the debug as true in bootstrap/app.php file and see the error on browser or try to tail error logs in apache and paste the error in here.

Comment: I have already posted head.blade.php and default.blade.php in which these html errors are occurring. In head.blade.php i am generating all css and js where as in default.blade.php i am generating img tag. Please look and suggest me the solution.

Comment: @Mandy, I meant html, which generated by Laravel. Go to your browser, go to 'view source' (Ctrl+U in Chrome), find part of html with <script...> and <link...> (your JS and CSS), copy and paste it to your post.

Comment: Updated, Kindly check.

Comment: It's legit html, so the problem is not with Laravel Collective or provider registration. Is you enter this in browser, do you see source code of your CSS: `http://localhost/testing/css/style.css` ? Or browser shows some kind of error?

Comment: No, I am not able to css or js or img in the browser, instead i am getting HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException.

Comment: Please check if your CSS and JS are in `public/testing` folder. Also, check `app/Http/routes.php` for testing route. Do you have something like 'testing', 'testing/{id}' or something like that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104839/discussion-between-mandy-and-alexey-mezenin).